# Geometry Nodes - How to access rotation in 3.0+?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Bit of a silly question, but apart from using an **Object Info** node, how can I get the rotation of an object?

I have a collection of objects which I'm separating by IDs. I'd really like to get the rotation of these objects. Example:

[image]

In 3.0 you're given direct access to 4 properties of an object: Position, Normal, Index and ID. The **Collection Info** node also allows access to both the *Original* and *Relative* properties of the objects. In addition to that each object origin (if centered) can be inferred from its **Position**.

I feel that with all this data there's enough to calculate the rotation but I have no idea what sort calculations should be performed here.

Comment: I think the Collection Info is used to create new instances of objects, therefore without any rotation, and so the rotation would always be 0. Still, it wouldn't hurt to be able to access the data of the original object. I imagine eventually it would be done by some kind of green datatype *instance* to orange datatype *object* converter - but currently I don't think any solution exists.